# STATIC_URL is not working in django

Tags: python, django, static

Please consider my seetings.py file given below of my django project

```
# Django settings for sadhana project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'test1',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'root123',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '#4twv0hz6f459ft+es3u$$z+uk#b@*_luj7)4-!4i9%(t9^ka_'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)




MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sadhana.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sadhana.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                 "/home/rahit/rahit/sahana/template/",
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'demo',             
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

i am using django 1.4 when i am trying to use {{STATIC_URL}} in template 
 like

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/feature_image_multi-party_video-conferencing.jpg" alt="Hi!" />
```

but images are not getting load on html page 
plz help me out what i am doing wrong

Comment: can you include an `img` tag from a rendered page? that will show what `STATIC_URL` is being rendered as.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`STATIC_URL` won't be added to the template context unless you add [`django.core.context_processors.static`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.core.context_processors.static) to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. So, you can do that, or you can alternatively use [the template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static) instead (Django 1.4+ only):

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "images/hi.jpg" %}" alt="Hi!" />
```

Comment: @ Chris i have a question it will work for both production and development or i need to do some additional for production environment

Comment: No, this is the same no matter what environment you're in.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between deplouying static files in production or development environments.

As far as I can see you're probably in a development environment, so you should add the static files dirs to the STATICFILES_DIR settings variable.
Or if your static files are located in the root of your django applicaiton add 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader' to the TEMPLATE_LOADERS settings variable.

Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ for more information on this subject.

Comment: Boss i was missing the context processor the time of rendering that template but images are still not uploading

Comment: Boss? I'd rather not have people call me like that. I'm just trying to help out. Might we see your model definition and specially the field that handles the file, probably an models.ImageField ?

Comment: oh sorry i could not created my model till yet i am just doing basic setups

Comment: Form class then ? Or how did you implement the upload part ?

Comment: *Please* don't recommend adding `static` to `STATICFILES_DIRS`. This is just flat out wrong. The directory specified by `STATIC_ROOT` should not even exist in development.

Comment: I did not recommend that explicitly. I didn't know his setup.