# django not found static files in the subfolder of static

Tags: python, django, static

django 1.6.5

My static files is under subfolder of static.

```
djangoprj
    djangoprj
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        __init__.py
    static
        myapp
            mystaticfiles
            ...
    apps
        myapp
            ...
            templates
                *.html
            ...
```

In my templates file, I link static file as full path.

```
<img src="/static/myapp/images/my.png" />
```

But those file are not found. I got 404 error.

When change settings.py as

```
STATIC='/static/myapp/'
```

I can get those static files. But I am not want to do that. Why dose it not wok, when `STATIC='/static/'`? Is there some easy way to solve this problem instead of doing command manaully, such as 'collectstatic'? I have put my static file in `static` folder, and I have used full path in my templates file. Why does it not work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you switch the static file folder to `'/static/myapp/'`

You should use `<img src="/static/images/my.png" />` in your tag.

Generally, you should use `{% static %}` template tag to do this, like below (assume `STATIC='/static/'`).

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<img src="{% static 'myapp/images/my.png' %}" />
```

**to learn more**, see the tutorial, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial06/

I suggest you to read all the tutorial (part1 - part6) in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/

So that you can know deep enough for the basis.

Comment: `<img src="{% static 'images/myapp/my.png' %}" />` should be `myapp/images/my.png` and `HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))` 

`STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(HERE, "static"),
)` in settings.py works either.

Answer (score 1):

You can found some help in these answers also

1. [static files problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631969/static-url-is-not-working-in-django)
2. [STATIC_URL Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184245/static-url-not-working-after-django-1-5-upgrade)

In my configuration I have a directory structure where static files are inside my app like this

```
djangoprj
    djangoprj
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        __init__.py
    apps
        myapp
            ...
            templates
                *.html
            static   
                myapp
                   mystaticfiles
            ...
            ...
```

In settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and in templates I use 'static' tags

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'posts/style.css' %}" />
```

I hope this can help you