# How to access static files in subfolders?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

fellows!
I have problems with static files. I still don't understand how this really works.
Problem is that when I try to keep files in subfolder of the app folder, Django returns 404.

Folders structure:

```
/static/
        product/
                images/
                       img.png
```

I am trying to access img.png in html template like this:

```
<img src="{% static "product/images/img.png" %}">
```

But 404 error is returned.

If I move img.png to the parent folder:

```
/static/
        product/
                img.png
                images/
```

And use this root:

```
<img src="{% static "product/img.png" %}">
```

All works fine.

This is my Settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'review', 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'review', 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = ['compressor.finders.CompressorFinder']
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (('text/x-scss', 'django_libsass.SassCompiler'),)
COMPRESS_URL = STATIC_URL
COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
```

What I should change so I can access static in the subfolders?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django not found static files in the subfolder of static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133302/django-not-found-static-files-in-the-subfolder-of-static)

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133302/django-not-found-static-files-in-the-subfolder-of-static